# Set <img> src attribute from another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, d3.js

I have an HTML page with SVG diplayed as an img.

This page changes the displayed SVG file using d3:
d3.select('img').attr('src', 'newFile.svg');

In other pages, I link to this HTML file and open it using window.open(...) which displays it with the "default" SVG file. Is there a way to set ('img').attr('src','...') from these other pages so that the required image is displayed instead?

Comment: When do you change the displayed SVG? Could you do it after loading the page?

Comment: @Lars - Yes. That is what I have tried calling so far. In Page0.html with  the button I have `code        <button type="button" class="sidebutton" 
                onclick="var file = './GJGraph.svg';
            if (noSVG) {
                file = file.replace('svg', 'png');
            }
            ;
            d3.select('img').attr('src', file);
            d3.select('a').attr('href', file);">
            GJGraph
        </button>.` But - can I achieve this from another file after calling window.open()?

Comment: It sounds like you would want to specify the image to show from the page you're redirecting from. You could pass this as a parameter to the target page.

Comment: @Lars - Thanks. Am I right that this would need server-side code rather than js or d3?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can pass parameters as part of the URL and extract them using Javascript. See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter).